# Swift: Enumate between tableView sections and row

Tags: ios, swift, enums, tableview

I would like to select a row in a tableView.
But insead of

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            switch indexPath.row {
                case 0:
                    ...
            }
        ...
}
```

this I would like to iterate

```
private enum Section {
    case section0
    case section1
    ...
}

private enum Section0 {
    case section0row0
    case section0row1
    ...
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch Section(rawValue: indexPath.section)! {
        case .section0:
            switch Section0(rawValue: indexPath.row)! {
                case section0row0:
                    ...
            }
        ...
}
```

like this.

Maybe there is a better way to code the enums... 
Is there a very clever solution someone is able to tell me?

Thanks :)

Comment: How about you start by telling us your use case - what exactly are you trying to do? There definitely is a better approach than what you're doing.

Comment: Agree with mag_zbc, you should give us a context to understand which is the best solution. For example what is your main goal? Is your table view static or dynamic? How is structured your data source?

Comment: The use of enums for sections is fine. For rows it's a bit more confusing. Why would you want to hardcode the number of rows you're dealing with? If all your content is hardcoded, just do it in a storyboard and skip having to write code altogether!

Answer (score -2):

there're tons of ways to solve this problem with that, one of the simplest but not the best one is the array of actions

for example:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

typealias closure = ()->()

extension Collection {

    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Element? {
        return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}


struct ListOfAction {

    private var list: Array<Array<closure>>

    init() {
        self.list = [[]]
    }

    mutating func append(_ at: IndexPath,method:@escaping closure) {
        self.list[at.section].append(method)
    }

    mutating func insert(_ at: IndexPath,method:@escaping closure) {
        self.list[at.section].insert(method, at: at.row)
    }

    func call(at:IndexPath) {
        self.list[safe: at.section]?[safe: at.row]?()
    }

    func getClosure(at: IndexPath) -> closure? {
        return self.list[safe: at.section]?[safe: at.row]
    }
}


var listOfAction = ListOfAction()
var idx = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
listOfAction.append(idx) {
    print("hello World")
}

listOfAction.insert(IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)) {
    print("bye World")
}

listOfAction.call(at: IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0))
listOfAction.getClosure(at: idx)?()
```

note: first at all you should care about the safety of the index;
second, you should modify the answer based on your requirements to become immutable or anything else.
the better way is using generic methods.

Comment: Did you even try to run your code? I'm guessing not, since it will crash with `Index out of range` error

Comment: @mag_zbc, did you import UIKit? also, please read the note part :-)
the code works fine
you should try this when you're constructing table view
and call your method  onAction,
the good part is it easier to use in Rx

Comment: What do you think happens when you subscript an empty array, which you do in `append` function? Also, why should I import `UIKit` if there is not a single `UIKit` class used?

Comment: @mag_zbc  read this part:  first at all you should care about the safety of the index

some approach like this :

subscript (safe index: Index) -> Element? {
        return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }

Comment: @mag_zbc the IndexPath with row and section initializer is inside the UIkit, it's not in the foundation :-)

Comment: Your `append(_ at: IndexPath,method:@escaping closure)` function will crash because it subscripts an empty array.

Comment: @mag_zbc about the append part, it's for table view construction you don't need to use at.row when it constructed syncrounsly, but if it async it should be inserted at row :-)